# Leaflet, coloring vectors while only displaying them at certain zoom levels

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Back again with another basic question. This has stumped me though.

I have a mountain bike trail map that displays icons for the trailheads/parking at all zoom levels. However, when the user zooms in (zoom level >=12), I want the GPS trails to display. I have the zoom controls/layer displays sorted, but symbolizing the trails (vectors) is where I'm stuck. I have tried numerous iterations, but none of fixed my issue.

Based on the way I've written my code, I can't for the life of me, figure out the proper way to apply style (color, opacity, weight).

[My map](http://millionsmaps.netne.net/ride/index.html), as it sits now. I centered the map (temporarily) around this specific trail.

The troubled code:

```
//Load Montgomery Bell (Green)
var mbGreenMarker = L.geoJson();
$.getJSON("trails/MBgreenTrail.geojson", function(json) {
    L.geoJson(json ,{
                style:  function (feature)
                    {
                        return {"color": "#00ff00","weight": 5,"opacity": 1}
                    }
            },
            {
                onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
                         layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.type);
                    }
            }
    ).addTo(map);
    mbGreenMarker.addData(json);
    });

map.on('zoomend ', function(e) {
     if ( map.getZoom() < 12 ){ map.removeLayer(mbGreenMarker)}
     else if ( map.getZoom() >= 12 ){ map.addLayer(mbGreenMarker)}
});
```

I feel like there is a more efficient way to load the GeoJSON, symbolize it and then pass it through the map.getZoom function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simplify how you add new GeoJSON data to your `mbGreenMarker` layer group, but still have it styled as desired, you could simply add the styling definition when setting up your `mbGreenMarker` layer group. It should automatically apply as well to later on added data (same for `onEachFeature`).

Note that with the code posted in your question, you actually build **twice** Leaflet vector layers from the same `json` data:

- once in an intermediate `L.geoJson` group, that is always on map, with your
  specified styling.
- a 2nd time when adding data to `mbGreenMarker`, **without** any custom styling. Only this 2nd layer will be switched on/off by your event listener.

You could get rid of the intermediate `L.geoJson` group and style it correctly within `mbGreenMarker`. The result will be a different behaviour than what your current code does. Hopefully it is closer to what you try to achieve.

```js
var mbGreenMarker = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      "color": "#00ff00",
      "weight": 5,
      "opacity": 1
    }
  }
}, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.type);
  }
});

// Add mbGreenMarker to map if current zoom is >= 12.
showmbGreenMarker();

$.getJSON("trails/MBgreenTrail.geojson", function(json) {
  mbGreenMarker.addData(json);
});

map.on('zoomend ', showmbGreenMarker);

function showmbGreenMarker() {
  if (map.getZoom() < 12) {
    map.removeLayer(mbGreenMarker)
  } else if (map.getZoom() >= 12) {
    map.addLayer(mbGreenMarker)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again ghybs. I feel like I tried many iterations of declaring mbGreenMarker with the style attributes (as you did). Must have done it just slightly wrong each time.


One thing to note, I had to add a 'null' when declaring the var mbGreenMarker. It works properly when coded as:
var mbGreenMarker = L.geoJson(null,({ ...

Comment: You are right, thanks, there is a missing 1st argument in `L.geoJson`. Will correct the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to check for the mbGreenMarker before adding/removing:

```
if (map.getZoom() >= 12 && map.hasLayer(mbGreenMarker)) {}
```

It's useful if the user can add/remove the layer in the layer control.

Finally you could add the scaling/viewport info as shown [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/mobile.html) so the app looks decent on phones.

[Example](https://getbounds.com/apps/getjson.html)

Comment: Thanks malcolm. I inspected your code and followed along with it. It actually helped me find a missing 'null' in my variable declaration. Also, I will certainly look into adding the scaling/viewport info to make it mobile friendly. Thank you!